# In Google Sheets I want to Filter out past dates with Apps Script but without filtering out the blank cells

Tags: google-apps-script, filter, range

In Google Apps Script I want to filter out all the rows with a past date in one of the columns.
I managed to do this but this filter also filters out the rows with a blank in the date-column. And I want those rows to stay.
So I tought: what if I make a range without that rows-without-a-date, and then filter the new range.
Is this possible or should I use another method?

This is the code I have:

```
function hidePastDates() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var today = new Date();
  var weekPast = new Date(today.getTime() - 1000*60*60*24*7) 
  var oldFilter = range.getFilter();

  if (oldFilter !== null) {  
    oldFilter.remove();
  }
  var filter = range.createFilter();  

  var filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria();

  filterCriteria.whenDateAfter(weekPast);
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(2,filterCriteria);
}
```

[This is my google sheets before I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rCQb.png)

[This is my google sheets after I ran the code and all the blank cells dissapear but I don't want that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO06I.png)

Comment: Welcome! Would you be able to edit your post, adding the code that you've written so far? That way we can see what you've tried and people can make suggestions or offer corrections.

Comment: I added my code.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
function reviewCurrentDatesOnly() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('sheet name');
  const [hA, ...data]=sh.getDataRange().getValues();//assume a single header with  data below
  let idx={};
  hA.forEach((h,i)=>{idx[h]=i});//return index for a given column header striing
  const today=new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate()).valueOf();//valueof today
  const tommorow=new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate()+1).valueOf();value of tomorrow
  data.forEach((r,i)=>{
    let dt=r[idx['date-column header']];
    let dtv=new Date(dt).valueOf();
    //requires all data values to be between today and tomorrow
    if(dtv>today && dtv<tommorow) {
      //put your code here
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I'm quite new in Apps Script so I don't fully understand. I added my code to my question and 2 screenshots of a simplified version of my sheet.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to filter the way you described. Even if you applied the filter manually in Sheets you'd get the same result. Alternatively, you could hide the rows:

```
function hidePastDates() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var rangeValues = range.getValues();
  var today = new Date();
  var weekPast = new Date(today.getTime() - 1000*60*60*24*7) 

  for (var i = 1; i < range.getHeight(); i++){
    if (rangeValues[i][1] != ""){
      if (rangeValues[i][1] < weekPast){
        sheet.hideRows(i+1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: That was the option I tried to avoid. :-) But if it's not possible I will go for this. Thanks a lot!